# Can't suggest an edit: "edit" link missing

Tags: support

I was going to try editing [this question](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/3848/async-task-runner-all-improvments-welcome), but there are no edit/retag links available:

[image]

At the same time, the link is there on other questions. For example:

[image]

I've run into another question where the "edit" link wasn't there, but I'm not sure if there's any similarity between them. They both were in the [c#](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/c%23) tag, but other C# questions had all the links as expected.

Am I missing something? (Other than the "edit" link. :))

Comment: Aha, I beat you to it.  :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's because they both have pending edits -- and since you don't have enough rep on CR to approve the edits, the `edit(0)` isn't visible to you.

I'll check all the pending edits and approve them now.